# CentOS 7 can't boot?

Tags: linux, centos7

I have CentOS 7 minimal installed on a VM and I have just done `yum update && yum upgrade` today. then I did a reboot.

Now CentOS wont boot up anymore, it stuck at a screen like below. I waited for an hour and it is still like this. I dont know what to do....

Any one knows if update would cause this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause.

I disabled SElinux....as part of requirement for a IBM software installation....

From grub set to selinux=0, server will boot up again, then vi selinux config to enable it again.